# matlab looping through rows of matrix non-singleton rhs dimensions

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, vector

I made an empty array and want to loop through each row:

```
theta = zeros(500,20);
for i=1:100
...
y = x*theta(i,:)';
...
end
```

So for each i I want to use the ith row vector, but I'm getting errors saying that "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"

Comment: Does  `x` really have  20 columns?

Answer (score 0):

We can't answer this question without knowing what x is in this scenario. Please update this with the definition of your x variable.

If you're multiplying two vectors together the matrix dimensions must agree, unless x is just a singular value. I can't replicate your error when I run the code, arbitrarily defining x.